# Unable to post links to an FB Event page using the Graph API

Tags: facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

We are trying to publish to the feed resource of an event using the Graph API. What happens is it seems to ignore any link that we post. It also does not seem the Graph API supports any option for posting a photo to the wall of an event.

We make the call to the event feed using the following parameters:

```
link='http://rfid-social-media.odinrfid.com/photo?photoId=000000000000000000102107'
name='John at Facebook Party'
message='Test Message 2'
caption='What a great time'
```

And we publish against the url:
https://graph.facebook.com/EVENT_ID/feed

The request response does go through successfully, but the link does not show up in the UI.

We can post a link to a regular page using the Graph API without issue. It does show in the UI with the link, thumbnail, caption, etc, all as it should.

***Thanks..***

Comment: Facebook provides 3 ways to interact with its data ! 1) graph API and 2) api.facebook.com 3) fql.................. If you want to just get the data you must use fql ! But as per your requirement you are trying to post something on facebook so you can use first and second option ! Now i m familiar with second option `api.facebook.com` It provides list of methods + parameters. Try this link http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/#administrative-methods

Comment: When you reply me Kindly Tag me

Comment: @NoOne - the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) is the best choice for simply retrieving data.  You can even make FQL queries in a call to the Graph API.

Comment: @NoOne - furthermore the link you gave is to the old REST API.  This is deprecated so Facebook does no support it anymore.  When you have problems with it *almost anyone* will tell you to upgrade to the new Graph API.  Take a look at it - its really easy to use.  There is even a tool so that you can poke around the API to see what data is available and how to access it. [Facebook Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

Comment: @Lix First of all thank you for information ! I have used graph in past projects but right now working with api.facebook.com ! It makes satisfy me ! Even I can do what I want ! Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Bug and its reported and marked as confidential
With the below text and its also contain security hole

[bug report link](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/320152154697289)

Below is my bug report text.
*Other details on this report are shown to Facebook employees only*

I recently attempted to post on an event's wall using the Graph API, but only the message is posted; Everything else is not showing. e.g.

- Link
- Picture
- etc

There is one more big thing that the post doesn't show; That this post is post "via a Facebook app"

**Note:** posting on a page or user wall worked and also normal messages posted on an event 's wall.

**The most important thing** is when the post is shown on the event's wall "it does not show that its posted by a Facebook Application".
This is very dangerous; For example I can make an application and post nonsense on a user's wall.  People will think that this is posted by the user.

*Thank you so much for creating this question*

Comment: Well there you go, it's a bug.  Easy 50 bounty win (and 15 score for accepting the correct answer) for you (if @John) does the right thing and give it to you since you did some research and filing a defect for him.

Comment: @DMCS thank you so much :) 
actually i am new in facebook i ask here some question but some are answered and some are not but i get success in almost all and i feel good to answer the peoples and solving there problems 
and yes you are right its easy bounty but this is really a very nice question if facebook resolve this is grate reward for me 
because as you its very wrong to post on event wall and people think  that this is posted by user because posted "by facebook app" is not shown think if i posted something wrong on event wall using app and people think its posted by user Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

For posting a photo to an event it seems to be a FB bug, subscribe and up the repo count so it gets attention
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/225316074217855?browse=search_4f2f7576c5bc32d87041759

Comment: its a similar bug, but not exact.  The bug report you show is for uploading photo content/data while the other bug, talking about in this question, is for a photo url/link.